# setting up mirrorlist for pacman.d in chroot / installing arch to usb stick

Tags: usb, arch-linux, chroot

I am new to ArchLinux and—moreover—deeper linux noodling. I am following the guide on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key).

I  am at a step where I set up the mirror list for repositories. I have my mirrorlist file in order (I think…) and I am ready to refresh the repositories by issuing the `pacman -Syyu` command.  My result is:

```
[root@ken /]# pacman -Syyu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed to update core (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to update extra (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to update community (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to synchronize any databases
error: failed to init transaction (no servers configured for repository)
```

I have seen a number of questions involving this step wherein the result is because of a number of errors suggesting that the mirrorlist text file has *uncommented* or *commented* servers.

I assume that this is referring to the hash before the http string and whether it has a a space between the two or not. Any clarification would really help!

Comment: Please, show your `/etc/pacman.conf` and `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` files